# ¿Como puedo transmitir datos de mysql a variables php?

Tags: php

El codigo es este

```
<?php
  session_start();

  require 'database.php';

  if (isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
    $records = $conn->prepare('SELECT id, user, email, password, rank FROM users WHERE id = :id');
    $records->bindParam(':id', $_SESSION['user_id']);
    $records->execute();
    $results = $records->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $user = null;

    if (count($results) > 0) {
      $user = $results;
    }
  }
if(!empty($user)){
    $logged = true;
} else {
    $logged = false;
    header("Location: /login.php");
}
```

Quiero transpasar el rank de la base de datos a una variable llamada $rank. y también el usuario a otra llamada $user. Un saludo

Comment: Ya probaste con `$rank = $user['rank'];`

Comment: A ok Gracias :)